# Drools wont take complex data structure

Tags: java, hashmap, drools, hashset

I have a problem when I want to make a complex data structure in Drools.

I have this data structure : `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>>` and I want to use it in Drools (in my .drl file).

When I tried in a simple java file it works perfectly with the code below.

```
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>> tmp = new HashMap<>();
    tmp.put(1,
        new HashMap<>(Map.ofEntries(
            Map.entry("A",
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
                    27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40))),
            Map.entry("B",
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
                    27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56,
                    57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70))))));
    System.out.println(tmp);
```

But the following code in Drools wont work :

```
declare type testMap
    data : HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>>
end

rule "Init"
    salience(100)
    when
        not (exists (inrMap()))
    then
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>> tmpMap = new HashMap<>();
        tmpMap.put(1, new HashMap<>(Map.ofEntries(entry("A", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70))),entry("B", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40))))));
        insert(new testMap(tmpMap));
end
```

I'm getting this error : `Cannot resolve type 'HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,HashSet<Integer>>> for field chunks in declared type testMap`

The problem is the data structure, because

- When I'm trying to declare the structure in a rule only to test if it works I get this error `Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Init'] org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.CompilationProblemAdapter@441a1f8f`
- I have other complex structure like `HashMap<HashSet<Integer>, HashSet<Integer>>` which are working.

Do you have any clue why it's not working ?

I've read the documentation too but didn't see anything.

I'm using Java 11 and Drools 7.59.0.FINAL.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use HashMap in rules. It's extremely non-performant. A Hashmap serializes to more than 20x times its original size.

Comment: Thanks for this tips I didn't knew it. I will try to bypass my problem by not using the Hashmap, but not sure it will works.

Comment: My company learned the hard way that HashMaps were the root of a lot of our problems.  Especially once you get into nested maps, though, it's always a good practice to consider refactoring to a simple data-carrier POJO or Record (if using newer Java).

Comment: I found a solution : I created a Java class with my HashMap and then surcharge all the methods. Then I created an object of this class in Drools and called the methods.

Comment: And thanks you for giving me another solution with the Record :)